# Parentheses when assigning variables in Stata

Tags: stata, generate

Does it make a difference if I have parentheses or not? Is this generating dummies or just assigning a value:
`generate byte  h_et = ( hvet )` and `generate byte  h_et = hvet` in Stata?

Comment: Nothing in your code implies creation of dummy variables. This code will copy one variable to another, with restrictions (1) the code will fail if `hvet` is string (2) the code will mess up if values can't be stored correctly in a `byte` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in any language (I know about) that allows parentheses, the vacuous answer is that parentheses make a difference if and only if they yield a result differing from what precedence of operators would yield.

Although your question is in terms of `generate`, examples using `display` (`di` is an allowed abbreviation) are easier to make plain. Just parenthesising an entire expression makes no difference to its meaning:

```
. di 42
42

. di (42)
42
```

But just as in elementary algebra, parentheses control which calculations are done first and so may make a difference.

```
  . di (1 + 2) / 3
1

. di 1 + 2 / 3
1.6666667
```

The precedence of operators is documented at

```
. help operators
```

Speaking for myself as a long-time Stata user and programmer, I have never tried to learn it and would not do well on a quiz about it. With very occasional exceptions, basic mathematical knowledge serves well enough, and as in high school mathematics, parenthesising aggressively is a better way to write clear and correct code than to rely on operator precedence.